# select a object key from an array and combining it to another object key

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of objects, what I want to do is just return _id and personalInfo but combine them into one

This is my sample array:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "57c4085234b1ccad0e7780f8",
    "personalInfo": {
      "firstName": "Ryan",
      "middleName": "sadsada",
      "lastName": "Tan",
      "nickname": "dsada",
    },
    "deleted": false,
    "updatedAt": "2016-08-29T10:02:58.900Z",
    "createdAt": "2016-08-29T10:02:58.900Z",
  }
]
```

What I have done so far is this:

```
    Patient.find({
        'deleted'   : false
    }, 'personalInfo', function (err, patients) {
        if (err) {
           return res.send(err);
        }
        res.send(patients);
    });
```

it gives me a result of this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "57c4085234b1ccad0e7780f8",
    "personalInfo": {
      "firstName": "Ryan",
      "middleName": "sadsada",
      "lastName": "Tan",
      "nickname": "dsada"
    }
  }
]
```

What I want is that it should return an array of objects like this

```
[
  {
    "_id": "57c4085234b1ccad0e7780f8",
    "firstName": "Ryan",
    "middleName": "sadsada",
    "lastName": "Tan",
    "nickname": "dsada"
    }
]
```

I have solved this problem by iterating the array with lodash to get the expected result I want. Is there a mongoose kind of way where I don't have to iterate the values manually to give me the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not possible in mongoose.. you have to map you're data in result of that query.. you can use lodash or undescore libary to map you're data easily

```
var _ = require('lodash');
Patient.find({
  'deleted': false
}, 'personalInfo', function(err, patients) {
  if (err) {
    return res.send(err);
  }
  var finalData = _.map(patients, function(obj) {
    return {
      "_id": obj._id,
      "firstName": obj.personalInfo.firstName,
      "middleName": obj.personalInfo.middleName,
      "lastName": obj.personalInfo.lastName      
    }
  });

  res.send(finalData);
});
```

Comment: Yes I have done the same work around to achieve this. I thought that there would be an alternative doing it on a mongoose kind of query(if there was) rather than doing manually looping it. Thanks for telling me it can't be done though. I'll just the work around we both have. Cheers